How to create a dynamic "que" of calculations in a query
Assume I have this table



event
amount
time




earned
100
1:00


spent
50
2:00


earned
50
3:00


spent
50
4:00


spent
50
5:00



I want to calculate when the transaction is break even (spent >= earned)
In the case of the example I have to put the second purchase (3:00) in a que after the first one and only when all amount earned in 1:00 was spent (which happens in our case on 4:00) I want to start reducing spent amount from the second purchase.
Is there a way I can do that in SQL (BQ)?
I thought maybe to use accumulated data and reduce from all purchases but there can be spending from other sources and in that case it doesn't work because I have more spent than earned.
I am expecting to use a query that tells me that for the first purchase all amount was spent at 4:00 and only from 5:00 started spending from the second purchase.

can you share expected results in the table

I think it's not that trivial but you can by combining a temp table with one side of it, another with a rolling sum and joining them where the sum equals (or exceeds?) the spent. Have you looked into rolling calculations?

You say about events spent, earned. What is 'purchase' - spent or earned.
